# Where to write the resolver when i'm not using GraphQLObjectType?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I'm writing a graphql project with express. I had defined User object like this:

```
const User = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
    name: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    },
    friends: {
      type: HistoricalPerformanceEvaluation,
      async resolve(user) {
        return db.users.findFriendsFor(user.id);
      },
    },
  }),
});
```

However, i'd like to use graphql syntax to create the schema and define it like this:

```
type User {
  name: String
  friends:  [User]!
}
```

Where should i write the resolver now? I'm not using Apollo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use addResolveFunctionsToSchema function from 'graphql-tools' to create schema with resolver functions.

```
import { addResolveFunctionsToSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
```

Comment: Can you run the resulting object without using the rest of Apollo?  I'm not obviously finding a way.

Answer (score 0):

Using the reference [graphql-js](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/) library, you can pass a root object to the GraphQL execution.  Any top-level queries and mutations are looked up on this object, and further nested query fields are looked up on the objects returned from that, and so on.

The example on the graphql-js front page includes this object:

```
// The root provides a resolver function for each API endpoint
var root = {
  hello: () => {
    return 'Hello world!';
  },
};
```

That object is then passed as a parameter to the [graphql](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/graphql/#graphql) entry point.